# what does those 2 types of values in column "Age" exactly mean in “horse-colic.data” dataset?

Tags: uses-of-open-data

I am learning [horse-colic](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Horse+Colic) dataset.

there are 2 types of values in column 2, 1 and 9.

dose that mean a record (a horse) is 1 year old or 9 years old?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation on the [link you provided](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Horse+Colic):

```
2: Age
1 = Adult horse
2 = Young (< 6 months)
```

Then 1 indicates an adult horse, and since there are no 2s in the second column of the data or test files, I'd guess that 9 indicates a horse younger than 6 months. *Let's check.*

Column 2 contains only the values 1 and 9. In the [data file](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/horse-colic/horse-colic.data), 24 of the 300 records have a value of 9 (8%), and in the [test file](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/horse-colic/horse-colic.test), 4 of 68 records have a value of 9 (6%). Similar percentages is a good sign that 9 means a young horse (instead of 2).

The missing data, of which they claim there is 30%, is marked by a `?` in other columns.

To get confirmation, feel free to contact the authors. And also consider reporting the bug to UCI.

Comment: heavily edited after checking data